# Looking for an alternative to duplicating a pom.xml file in jenkins job

Tags: .net, maven, jenkins

I am building with jenkins/maven a dotnet solution. When the process starts, it looks at the packaging tag and decides accordingly to either build a xl-deploy zip file or use the provided nuspec file and build a nuget package.
The behaviour is currently driven by the value of the packaging tag.

We never had this requirement before, so it was not an issue to be able to do one thing (XLDeploy) OR the other (nuget package). But now we need to be able to do both things with the same pom.xml file, in the same jenkins job.

- I tried to put packaging in a profile -> no go
- I tried to overload packaging with -Dpackaging -> no go (this is a maven property not a pom property if I've read correctly)

My current solution is to duplicate the pom.xml file and change the tag in each copy -> I do not find this to be a clean solution.

Can someone come up with a better idea ? (I know TeamCity can do this but migrating is not yet an option)

Many thanks,
regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a pom to do the packaging which has a plugin similar to

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then in your assembly.xml you can add both formats, each time even if one of them is not used.

```
<formats>
  <format>zip</format>
  <format>tar</format>
</formats>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but This won't work due to having a in-house plugi which does the heavy lfting with nuget/nuspec part. I ended doing 2 poms, removing the XLdeploy part and crea

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip but this won't work due to having an in-house plugin which does the heavy lfting with nuget/nuspec part. 
I ended doing 2 poms, removing the XLdeploy part and creating 2 jenkins jobs, one for XLDeploy and one for nuget.
The in-house plugin is too linked to maven lifecycle (and due for retirement pretty soon).